# Registering a VM with an ESX4i Node

Tags: vmware

Just wondered if someone could explain why it isn't possible to add a VM to the inventory of an ESX4i server using a powerCLI script

Answer (score 1):

ESXi doesn't have write access from PowerCLI.

In my opinion, the easiest way to register is by using the GUI (datastore browser) browsing to your vmx file, right click on the file, and select the option to register it.